# Automatic creation of Product Display for Drupal commerce?

Tags: commerce

Is there any way to automatically create a *Product Display* when I create a Product with the [commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) module. The product display should references the product.

I'm thinking of using rules to accomplish this but not sure.

My client finds it complicated to create a product and then a product display.

Should I go with [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) module to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your products and products display has a 1 to 1 relationship, you could use views to display your products instead. You also could do it with rules or custom code. Rules allow to create entities so it's all a matter of filling out data on the product display node with the product date.

The idea behind product displays is that you want to display multiple variants or related products. An example would be to display the variations in size, color, material etc and from the same node be able to select the product I want.

IMO you should go for Commerce and not ubercart. It's far more flexible and powerful. It's also better integrated with Drupal 7 features and the main modules in Drupal like, Views, entity, rules, and is doesn't have the history of legacy code that needs to be supported like Ubercart does.

Comment: I didn't know that I can get 'products' inside views. You mean that I don't need to create a 'product display' to get 'products' inside a view?

Comment: @chefnelone Products are entities like nodes and you can display them via a view just like you can with nodes (and comments, users and ...). The only difference is that if you go to node/[nid] you can see a node but if you go to product/[product_id] you get a 404 because the url doesn't exist. You could create this through Views, or you could create a public url for products just like there exists for nodes. This require coding and understanding entities and fields.

Comment: thanks, I thought Products wasn't entities like other nodes because Products don't have multilingual capabilities like other nodes.

Comment: @chefnelone Do users have multilingual capabilities? Anything that can have fields is an entity.

Comment: you are right, my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

There's also a commerce contrib module that creates products:

[Commerce Bulk product Creation](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_bpc):

> The module also provides various ways to create display nodes for the
>   newly-created products:
>
> - Redirect user to node creation form (with title and product reference
>     filled in).
> - Silently create display node referencing all created
>     products.
> - Silently create one display node for each created product.
>     This will greatly speed up the task of adding numerous products at
>     once.

I haven't tried it myself yet. But i just know it's out there.

Answer (score 1):

Check [inline_entity_form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) project on drupal, with that one you can create your product (variation too) inside the node product display.. i invite you to checkout the drupal 7 install profile commerce kickstart V2 for watching the way that drupal commerce is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Also https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_display_manager module can be usefull for creating new *Product display* node while creating *Product variations*

> Features:
>
> ```
> A dedicated display manager page allowing you to drag products into or out of  
> display nodes as desired.
> Manage references to a product directly on the product form (New: now supports 
> multiple references).
> ```